# System recovery failed due to interruption, no recovery disc available

Tags: windows-installation

On a HP Pavillion running Windows 10, system recovery was interrupted and just hanging there with the error message "restoration incomplete".  I tried it again a month later and got a little further, the new error message stating "Install Windows.  Windows could not complete the installation.  To install Windows on this computer, restart the installation."   I have no recovery media, no other working PC and only a phone that I'm using to type this.  I'm also in a pretty remote area and don't know anyone here yet, so can't ask for help locally.  With few options that will provide the instant gratification I seek, can I take a hard drive from another HP Pavillion (bad charging jack) and, with a hard drive enclosure, use it to boot up the current laptop so I can then download the recovery media?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some sort of USB or DVD which has the Windows setup files on it. Then you'll be able to boot the laptop from that USB/DVD and re-install Windows with it.

You can download the Windows 10 files from the Microsoft website.